# install .net framework 4.5 along with project primary setup

Tags: c#, .net, installshield, setup-project, advanced-installer

I want to create setup project for my application but since my project uses .net framework 4.5 I want .net frame work 4.5 setup file being install after (or before) my app setup when setup.exe clicked
I used Install shield and Advanced Installer as well as vs setup project

instal shield (v 10) did not even know .net frame work 4.5 in prerequisite section. Advenced Installer had better support on .net frame work but it consist only launch condition in which if condition is not true the installation stops but it doesn't have a section to get .net setup file and install it along with main setup

is there any setup builder app that get one setup file (msi or exe) and install it along with main setup ???

thanks in advance

Comment: NSIS can do everything: [check if net framework is installed](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_Detect_.NET_Framework), [download/install .Net Framework](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download_and_Install_dotNET_45) and then continue with installing your program. It has weird script language however.

Comment: The days that installing .NET yourself were a good idea are over and done with.  .NET 4.5 reached [end-of-life 6 days ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx).  Only thing you should do is check if it is there, much like you'd check that the user has a supported Windows version.

Comment: what am I supposed to do with script I make .bat file of it but console shows and then quickly closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Installer has builtin support for Prerequisites, .NET is in the list of predefined ones. However, you need to create at least a Professional project type.

Once you have that project type you can add .NET as prerequisite and the setup will get the EXE and launch its installation, if it is missing from the target machine.

[image]